# Nginx worker process concurrent users limit

Tags: performance, nginx, server

I do know that on increasing the load we could make Nginx to use multiple worker process at the same time as it uses Reactor pattern.
But what I am trying to figure out is if its possible to load more than one worker_process without increasing the load i.e., two requests should be served to two different worker process.
So do we have some sort of directive through which could set the limit on number of requests received by individual worker process ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that we could use worker_connections directive to declare the number of open connections from different client which single worker_process could handle at a time.
Could be found at:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_connections